# How to input this particular complicated equation in Mathematica?

Tags: input

```
  tornadom  = 
        (m)(Pi)/d
        (m π)/d
        lambdan  = 
        (n)(Pi)/h
        (n π)/h

u[x,y,t]= 
Re[F[x,y,t]] = 
(Q∘)Cos[(ω)(t)]-((16)(Q∘)/dh)
Sum[(Sin[tornado (x)]/tornado)Sin[lambda (y)/lambda],{{m,n},Infinity}]
```

> Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed.

I am a beginner in mathematica and stuck in writing following equation,kindly help me to solve this problem.I'll be very thankful to you guys. p.s it is incomplete because i got an error.
[image]

[image: mathematica equation]

Comment: @MMM Sure sir. updating the post.

Comment: I am not from ARMY, so no need to call me sir

Comment: Isn't `Re[F[x,y,t]]` a part of derivation not a part of final equation? Get rid of `\[SmallCircle]` next to the `Q`, it is an infix operator. Take a look at `Sum's` documentation and correct the syntax.

Comment: @Kuba thanks alot

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed MMM's answer. But some additional tips won't harm.

Comment: @MMM ok brother,thank you.  :)

Comment: @MMM Neither equation-solving nor complex  tags should belong to this post. If you edit try to make it consitent.

Comment: @Artes my bad, I didn't notice that.

Comment: hello @MMM sorry to disturb you again. if you don't mind then kindly review my this question. i cannot tag you there, so my apologies for using this thread.
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139170/how-to-input-given-complicated-equation-in-mathematica
i will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is, how to input the mathematical expression in to *Mathematica*, then here it is,

```
xi[m] = m*Pi/d;
lambda[n] = n*Pi/h;
F[x_, y_, t_] = Q0*Cos[w*t] 
            - 16*Q0/dh*Sum[ Sum[Sin[xi[m]*x]/xi[m]*Sin[lambda[n]*y]/lambda[n]*(g1[m, n, t] 
            - w*Integrate[(Cos[w*(t - s)]*g2[m, n, s] + Sin[w*(t - s)]*g1[m, n, s]), 
            {s, 0, t}]), {n, 0, Infinity}], {m, 0, Infinity}]
```

**Note**

You will get `1/0` because of `xi[m]` and `lambda[n]`.